# Composer fails for private Gitlab Repository

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, gitlab

i have a new project where i want to require a private Gitlab Repository. Both Repositories belong to me, so i can change whatever i want.

The `composer.json` of the project looks like:

```
{
    "name": "thisismyproject",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "email": "me@me.me"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://gitlab.com/me/my-wordpress-plugin.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0@dev",
        "me/my-wordpress-plugin": "dev-master"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "wp-content/plugins/{$name}": [
                "type:wordpress-plugin"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "gitlab-token" : {
            "gitlab.com": "thisismysupersecrettoken"
        }
    }
}
```

The `composer.json` of the wordpress plugin repository looks like:

```
{
    "name": "WordPress Plugin",
    "description": "lorem",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "email": "me@me.de"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SomeNamespace\\": "."
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

The output of `composer update -vvv` looks like:

```
Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/me%2Fmy-wordpress-plugin
Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/me%2Fmy-wordpress-plugin/repository/branches?per_page=100
Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/me%2Fmy-wordpress-plugin/repository/files/composer%2Ejson/raw?ref=14
3c1818bfc96dcaa4ee5c26cc0bd379c395491c
Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/me%2Fmy-wordpress-plugin/repository/tags?per_page=100
Reading composer.json of WordPress Plugin (v1.0.0)
Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/me%2Fmy-wordpress-plugin/repository/files/composer%2Ejson/raw?ref=14
3c1818bfc96dcaa4ee5c26cc0bd379c395491c
Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/gitlab.com/me/my-wordpress-plugin/143c1818bfc96dcaa4ee5c26cc0bd379c39549
1c into cache
Importing tag v1.0.0 (1.0.0.0)
Reading composer.json of WordPress Plugin (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package me/my-wordpress-plugin could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the pa
ckage name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see  for more details.

Read  for further common problems.
```

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked for the `Problem 1` and potential causes ?

Comment: Any custom repositories that you use *MUST* be defined in the root composer.json. You have to duplicate that section from your project package to anything that wants to use it. You should also be using proper, meaningful vendor namespaces and package names, not `me/mything`, even for internal packages like this.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay thats the reason im asking...

Comment: @Sammitch it is and yes, its just for the question here

Comment: Also, I've been down the whole "private packages" rabbit-hole before, and you should probably look at using something like [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) before you erode your sanity too much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are receiving the error because your package name is not the same.

To fix it, you need to update the name in the `composer.json` of your WordPress plugin.

```
{
    "name": "me/my-wordpress-plugin",
    "description": "WordPress Plugin",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "email": "me@me.de"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SomeNamespace\\": "."
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

The name should match the `key` in the `require` of your main `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0@dev",
    "me/my-wordpress-plugin": "dev-master"
},
```